# this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Monet.Models.AgentTransmission]'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I have two tables in my SQL database, one for storing the agent (`AgentTransmission`) and the other logs the transmission history (`TransmissionHistory`) of the agent (there will only be one successful, or reply status "S", record on the logging table per agent).

I need to grab the information from the `AgentTransmission` table according to a filter set based on the dates of the `TransmissionHistory` table. However, since the view I need to send this to is looking for `@model IEnumerable<Monet.Models.AgentTransmission>` I am getting the following error

`The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List1[<>f__AnonymousTypeb'18[System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Int64,System.String,System.String,System.Nullable'1[System.DateTime],System.Boolean,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.String,System.Nullable'1[System.DateTime]]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[Monet.Models.AgentTransmission]'.`

I'm pretty new to Linq/Entity Framework so if anyone can give me a hint as to what's going on that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
        var agents = (from a in db.AgentTransmission
                        join t in db.TransmissionHistory on
                            a.ID equals t.TranTableId
                        where a.RecordStatus.Equals("C") &&
                            a.WelcomeLetter &&
                            t.ReplyResult.Equals("S") &&
                            EntityFunctions.DiffDays(t.TransmittedOn, startDate) <= 0 &&
                            EntityFunctions.DiffDays(t.TransmittedOn, endDate) >= 0
                        select new
                        {
                            a.BankName,
                            a.DRMCompanyName,
                            a.Pendist,
                            a.FirstName,
                            a.LastName,
                            a.MiddleInitial,
                            a.ReferenceNumber,
                            a.AgencyId1,
                            a.AgencyIdType1,
                            a.EffectiveDate,
                            a.JIT,
                            a.Email,
                            a.LocationStreet1,
                            a.LocationStreet2,
                            a.LocationCity,
                            a.LocationState,
                            a.LocationZip,
                            a.CreatedDate
                        });


        return View(agents.ToList());
```

Comment: Instead of using `var`, you can type the variable (in this case, `List<AgentTransmission>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing an anonymous object to your view (the `new {}` part of the select) whereas your view expects an object of type `IEnumerable<AgentTransmission>` (because that's what you used in your `@model` declaration). You should be coherent in the model you are passing to your view. Ideally design a view model and have your select statement return a `new SomeViewModel` and then make you view strongly typed to `@model IEnumerable<SomeViewModel>`.

Comment: In what way would i need to alter the query? I changed the `select new` statements to read `BankName = a.BankName` etc, then created a `viewmodel` with those fields. I tried dumping the query into `List<WelcomeLetter> letters = agents.ToList();` and even sending the `agents` object to the view, which is now looking for a `WelcomeLetter` viewmodel, however missing something here.

Comment: So inside your action you must have `select new MyViewModel { ... }` and then have your view strongly typed to `@model IEnumerable<MyViewModel>`. In `MyViewModel` you should include all the properties shown in your question of course.

Answer (score 0):

As the error is trying to tell you, you declared your view as taking a collection of `AgentTransmission`.

You can't pass it a collection of anonymous types.